# Spring Cloud Task not started with Spring Cloud Stream using RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-task

I am experimenting with Spring Cloud APIs as part of microservices course.

To setup server-less task, I am using Cloud Task, Cloud Stream(RabbitMQ), and Spring Web.

For this I have setup following projects:

Serverless task to be executed - 
https://github.com/Omkar-Shetkar/pluralsight-springcloud-m3-task

Component to receive Http request from user and submit to RabbitMQ - 
https://github.com/Omkar-Shetkar/pluralsight-springcloud-m3-taskintake

Sink component to receive TaskLaunchRequest and forward to cloud task -  https://github.com/Omkar-Shetkar/pluralsight-springcloud-m3-tasksink

Having setup above components, ensured that task component is available in local maven repository.
[image]

After initiating a POST request onto `/tasks` in `pluralsight.com.TaskController.launchTask(String)` I see a HTTP response.

[image]

But, I couldn't see any update in tasklogs DB associated with serverless task.
This means, task it self is not called.

In RabbitMQ console I could see connections are established from intake and sink components but I don't see any message exchange happening.

[image]

Queue with name `tasktopic` is having ZERO message count.

[image]

Appreciate any pointers and suggestions on how to proceed on this to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issue with my current implementation:

In intake and sink modules -> *application.properties*, binding property key was wrong.

It should be:

In intake module

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=tasktopic
```

In sink module

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=tasktopic
```

Also, local cloud deployer versions were incompatible in sink modules pom.xml.

Updated the same to:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-deployer-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

With these changes, I am able to get RabbitMQ messages.

Answer (score 0):

@EnableTaskLauncher annotation is missing in TaskIntakeApplication.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTaskLauncher
public class PluralsightSpringcloudM3TaskintakeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PluralsightSpringcloudM3TaskintakeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose @EnableTaskLauncher should be with sink task. After I made suggested change, getting following error: Field taskLauncher in org.springframework.cloud.task.launcher.TaskLauncherSink required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.task.TaskLauncher' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.task.TaskLauncher' in your configuration.